# Quickest way to install a deb only available in an older version of ubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Although I am sure a duplicate is somewhere in AU, I could not find it.

- I'm in 14.10

I need

- configure-trackpoint

What is the most simple and straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: 14.10 is a development version of Ubuntu and is not supported here.

Comment: @saiarcot895 The problem would not change if the OP was using 14.04. Installing an old (unsupported) package is the general question.

Comment: Agreed; however I did make a mistake; I assumed the package was not available in the repos; I did actually find it. (libgnomeui). There is however other applications that make this question applicable.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: I think this really depends on the application and it's dependencies, so no "one size fits all" approach. I recently installed a 12.04 deb in 14.04 and it worked fine, but that isn't always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo dpkg -i myprogram.deb --force` I have not tested whether it will work or not with downgrading packages, but there are more options for dpkg that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - this one is a little old - distributed with Ubuntu Lucid?  I think you can find the library at http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/libgnomeui/2.0/

Comment: That was my bad; this is actually still in the repos. I changed the question to reflect an actual depreciated lib. You can find it by searching libgnomeui in synaptic... useful for any other confused users who happen to come across this thread.